# How to I connect to different tenant's database in Power BI Embeded?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

There are multiple tenant databases (SQL or Azure Cosmos DB) with same schema, how do I change the connection during report runtime?

While I can set the "Connection string" in Query Advanced Editor with Parameter, it is no possible to set the password/key. And the "import" won't work for each of them.